# How to get more detailed error messages from net.ssh.authentication Ruby

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am trying to view detailed error messages from an SSH server

what I have:

`require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'sshkey'`

k = SSHKey.generate(
  type:       "RSA",
  bits:       2048
)
begin
Net::SSH.start("x.x.x.x","username", :keys=>[k.public_key], :verbose => Logger::DEBUG, :auth_methods => ['publickey']) do |ssh|
   end
  rescue SocketError
    puts "Host name cannot be resolved."
    strBypass = true
  rescue Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed
    puts "  Authentication failure"
  end

I am particularly looking for a 'SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE' response from the ssh server.

Please help